# Location of Global Shortcuts in OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, shortcut

Xcode 4' default shortcut for `FindTab` is `Cmd+3` and the default shortcut for `Issue Navigator` is `Cmd+4`.

My problem is that `Cmd+1` and `Cmd+2` work fine, but `Cmd+3` and `Cmd+4` do not.

All the other applications have the same problem. For example, in Finder, `Cmd+1` and `Cmd+2` works but not `Cmd+3` and `Cmd+4`.

It seems `Cmd+3`, `Cmd+4` are defined in somewhere as global shortcuts, but I can't find them.

I have looked for `Keyboard' in 'System Preferences' and installed and looked in 'KeyRemap for Macbook' but I couldn't find the keys.

Can anyone tell me where to find these keys?

My OS version is 10.7.4. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may be having trouble with Cmd-Shift-3 and Cmd-Shift-4 (Defined in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Screen Shots).

Cmd-3 and Cmd-4 are usually apps specific (eg, select tab 3 or 4 in Chrome).

**Update:**

- Check if you are using a third party app that captures those keys. I used to have a issue similar to that when using Skitch: it would capture Cmd-Shift-7, disabling the toggle comments functionality on several editors.
- Also check the Services menu (XCode > Services) where those bindings may even be publicized.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. But still doesn't work after turn them off. Probably it's not the reason.